# partial view was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have following controller code:

```
public MyController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult MyPartialViewAction()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder/_MyPartialView",PartialViewModel);
    }
}
```

and my Index view has the following code :

```
@HTML.Action("MyPartialViewAction")
```

When I run the Web app I get HttpException with InnerExceptionMessage as :

> InnerException    {"The partial view '~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder/_MyPartialView' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder/_MyPartialView"}    System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

What I have tried till now :

- Tried moving `_MyPartialView` from `~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder` to `~/Views/Shared/` and `~/Views/MyControllerFolder` but still error exists
- Tried changing my Index View code to `@HTML.RenderAction()` but no luck.

Any inputs on where I'm going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to add the .cshtml extension to the view name:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder/_MyPartialView.cshtml",PartialViewModel);
```

Comment: yep that worked, thought Razor would automatically take care of the file extensions. Thanks @Maess

Comment: I had the same problem.  I think maybe because we used the "~/Views" instead of the default path, we then have to write out the entire file path (including the extension) because we are now being explicit with the View's name.

Comment: I also had the error: "The [_myPatialView] partial view was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations."  I had to remove the .cshtml extension to render the partial view properly.

Answer (score 75):

Just in case the selected answer is not working for you:

I changed the build action of the cshtml file to Content and it fixed it.

Comment: Thanks Sanvir, any ideas why when the cshtml file was made my Build Action was set to "None". Seems its a bit of weird functionality to me?

Comment: This usually happens when I copy and paste a cshtml file, instead of adding a new one.

Comment: same thing happened to me - file got set to embedded resource somehow.  changed it back to Content and it worked of course.

Comment: For anyone who didn't immediately know how to change the build action:

Right click File > Properties > Build Action > Choose Content.

(Make sure you're not debugging as the drop down will be disabled)

Comment: This got me in the right direction, but having the cshtml-files in a separate project, I had to set build action to EmbeddedResource

Comment: Wow so many years and VS versions later ... still happened in VS22! Lucky to have found this fantastic answer.

Comment: Still useful in 2023! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

If the answers are still not working for you and you have put your partial in a nested folder inside of partials, ensure that you provide the full path to the partial with the extension.

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Partials/Components/_AdvancedComponentRenderer.cshtml", Model.Content);`

Answer (score 5):

Also double check for spaces after your filename, before the ".cshtml". I had inserted one blank space accidentally after my filename, and this disrupted the automatic behavior of PartialView() for me.

Answer (score 2):

Hope, this code helps you (In **".cshtml"** file)

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines
@inject ICompositeViewEngine Engine

....
string path = "../Themes/User/_head";

@if (Engine.FindView(ViewContext, path, isMainPage: false).Success)
{
    <partial name="@path" for="@Model" />
}
else
{
    <partial name="../Themes/Admin/_head" />
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message because the partial view was added to the project file (.csproj) but was not actually present on disk.