# No partialview found at location?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net MVC app.  There is a partial view at the following location:

> Areas/myarea/Views/Home/_MyPartial.cshtml

When I try to reference this partial:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Areas/myarea/Views/Home/_MyPartial.cshtml", Model);
```

I get this error:

> The partial view '/Areas/myarea/Views/Home/_MyPartial' was not found or no view engine supports the
>   searched locations.  The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Areas/myarea/Views/Home/_MyPartial

The host view is at /Views/Home/

Is my syntax wrong or is there something else I need to do for this to work?

Comment: Look at the location you referenced in your code, look at the location specified in the error message, and then look at the location you actually put the file.

Comment: `Areas/myarea/Home/View/_MyPartial.cshtml` != `Areas/myarea/View/_MyPartial.cshtml`

Comment: Typo - it's now fixed.

Comment: Are any of your partials working?  What's different about those?

Comment: Other partials are working.  I guess the difference is that they are not in an area.

Comment: Looks like you have to add the extension: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054264/partial-view-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-locations.  That works for me.  If it is in some custom folder (areas included), the extension is required?