# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post an object into json server but I got the 500 internal server error. In this code is working fine in localHost but live not working, any this wrong in my code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/Booking/CheckAvailability',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  data: { 
    LocationID: locationID, 
    VenueID: venueID, 
    FacilityID: facilityID, 
    BookedFromDate: bookedFromDate, 
    BookedToDate: bookedToDate, 
    FromTime: fromtime, 
    ToTime: Ttime 
  },
  traditional: true,
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
      $("#VenueBooking").show();
    }
    if (data.False) {
      alert("Aleardy Booked");
    }
  },
  error: function (ex) {
    alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
  }
});
```

Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckAvailability(int locationID, int venueID, int facilityID, string bookedFromDate, string bookedToDate, string fromTime, string toTime)
        {

            try
            {
                Get_Location();
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    locationInformation check = new locationInformation();
                    bool suc = check.CheckAvailability(bookedFromDate, bookedToDate, fromTime, toTime);
                    if (suc == false)
                    {
                        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Checked successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else if (suc == true)
                    {
                        return Json(new { False = true, message = "Checked successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does this method (Get_Location();) do?

Comment: @SehaxX get drop down value

Comment: Why not update your api code so it outputs the exception - obviously catching and returning the view is not working so perhaps you need to return a view with the exception message so you can see what exception is being thrown

Comment: @Pete   https://ibb.co/jexWzo network tab message

Comment: For a start you have `return View()` in your controller which would cause an exception if that is executed since you have specified `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to look at the network tab in the browser developer tools if you cannot debug the server. Hopefully you can get insight on why the error is being thrown. Select the failed request and look at the response.

Try to make sure the CheckAvailabilty view is added. See answer below:

[partial view was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054264/partial-view-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-locations)